# building a out-of-tree module on Beagle Bone Black

Tags: module, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

Machine Details :

```
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Problem Details:

In a attempt to write `out-of-tree` modules on beagle bone black(as intree modules require me to compile/flash them again and again ), i have logged in to `beagle bone black revc` through ssh client, which gives me a command line interface via `putty`, as in general out-of-tree module development, i have tried to compile module with the following make file

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# kbuild part of makefile
        obj-m  := module.o

        #module-objs := module.o
else
# normal makefile
        KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
        PWD  := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

endif
```

resulting an error

```
root@beaglebone:~/lddgeek# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.13-bone47/build M=/root/lddgeek modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.13-bone47/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

but when i parse to  the path of KDIR i did not find build folder as we find it in an normal ubuntu installed on x86

if i have to develop drivers/modules `out-of-tree` on a Beagle how could i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason i was not able to compile was i was missing the `kbuild` environment , i need to install kernel headers which will give me the capability to compile out-of-tree/external modules

```
#wget https://raw.github.com/gkaindl/beaglebone-ubuntu-scripts/master/bb-get-rcn-kernel-source.sh
#chmod +x bb-get-rcn-kernel-source.sh
#./bb-get-rcn-kernel-source.sh
```

The above steps actually helped me in solving the errors faced , while i was able to insert,remove the hello world module that i was trying to build

Comment: I had a similar issue and this worked for me too. Thanks!